# Nouns without an article as in e.g. "Empire is not always a good thing"

Tags: english, terminology, nouns, articles

Consider the highlighted nouns below.

> **Empire** is not always a good thing.  (The burden of **empire**, like its benefit, was not equitably shared.)
>
> Some great apes have **theory** of mind.  (**Theory** may tell us one thing, but practice teaches us another.)
>
> Using **force** to chastize one's own ally is not **war**.
>
> **Man** is the measure of all things.

And compare:

> We lost **an empire**, but won a market.
>
> Darwin proposed **a theory**.
>
> In **a war** of attrition, you need **a force** equal to those of your foe and the "neutral" noncombatants combined.
>
> I saw **a man**.

To the top line, please also add this from *Empire Made Me: An Englishman Adrift in Shanghai* by Robert Bickers (emphasis added).

> But one thing which does strike one is that Maurice Tinkler took **empire** too seriously.  In *The Road to Wigan Pier*, former imperial policeman George Orwell wrote about the fact that every imperialist knew that the rhetoric of **empire** was all airy fluff at heart, and that **empire** was the brute fact of power. . . .  For Tinkler, it wasn't merely that **empire** was the geopolitical status quo. . . .

**Question**

Is there a term in grammar or linguistics for the type of "bare" nouns (those without an article) shown in the first two sentences (i.e. *empire* and *theory*)?

It could be a term unique to English grammar or applicable to the phenomenon in any language.

**Background**

If the question is perfectly clear, you don't have to read this background.

*What I mean by the "phenomenon":*

It seems to me that *empire* and *theory* are different from *force* and *war*.

With *force* and *war*, they seem to have two established usages, countable and uncountable.  As a result, saying, "Using force to chastize one's own ally is not war," may not amount to a special adaptation.  (If you are wondering, the sentiment is from the Peloponnesian War.)

But with *empire* and *theory*, it seems perhaps the countable use is better established, and the "bare" instances may therefore look like a special adaptation.  (Theory of mind here means one ape's attribution of mind to another ape as in:  "Oh, he doesn't know the panther is coming.  I should warn him.")

Anyway I'm not insisting that my characterization is accurate.  I am only trying to bring out the difference a little bit.

As for *man* I don't know where that comes from.  We don't say, "Lion is a mammal."

*What I'd like to know:*

If there is a standard term for cases like *empire* and *theory*, that's what I'd like to know.

If not, terms to include some broader range of "bare" nouns would also help.

If not, I would appreciate pointers (e.g. Internet links) to standard treatments of the phenomenon, again whether for English or not.

If you are a grammarian or linguist and proceed to give an account of it right here, deny that it exists (i.e. *empire* and *theory* are no different from *force* and *war*), etc. that too would be appreciated.  But in that case, please tell me your qualifications (degree, teaching post, etc.).

If *empire*, *theory*, *force* and *war* are all doing the same thing, I would still like to know the standard terms of discourse.  Thanks!

**P.S.**

I have supplied other examples for top two lines (those in parentheses and the long quote) in response to comments received.  I hope at least some of them may be grammatical.

Comment: I find your examples with _empire_ and _theory_ both of dubious grammaticality. I can only make sense of the _theory_ one if "Theory of mind" is being treated as a sort of proper noun. A pair of words for "with/without article" is "arthrous/anarthrous".

Comment: Just as an aside, Colin, is this parallel to something like 'presence of mind' to you?

Comment: Curiously enough, it occurs to me that *water*, for instance, is a sort of proper noun if we allow that a proper name is a name given to one thing and no other. The species HOH has that name, and no other. In the same way, when we say *benefit of empire* we may be thinking of the species, of which this or that particular empire is an instance. (Of course, many people are called *Chris* etc., but I think we can tweak the idea of *given to one thing and no other* so it survives this objection.)

Comment: If the examples are all ungrammatical, I think that's OK too. The question would say:  Grammatical or no, here's a tendency or type of use. What did linguists have to say about it?

Comment: I just encoutered [this question](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/224/is-the-countable-vs-mass-noun-distinction-common-outside-english?rq=1) which is related to yours and might contain helpful hints, although the question is not exactly the same.

Comment: Abstract nouns do not require determiners in English: The idea of empire is difficult to understand. Wealth has its virtues. Force, theory, empire and man can all be used as **abstract nouns**.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, the closet terms I could think of are:

- **generic interpretation** (as oppsed to "accidental interpretation", at least I guess that is what you would call the opposite), which rather seems to apply to concrete and countable nouns though: *She bakes bread* (in general, e.g. as a profession, vs. a specific cake in a concrete situation: *She bakes the bread*)
- **non-discrete nouns** (Haegman & Guéron, p. 55), which don't allow for pluralisation (like * *hatreds*, * *justices* as compared to *the loves*, *several charities*, which are also abstract but still to some extend countable  in an appropriate context) - but obviously, *wars* or *theories* is grammatically acceptable
- Haegeman & Guéron (p. 67) also, like you, use the term **bare noun** in combination with **non-overt determiners**; but their examples rather seem to apply for non-abstract entities used as an NP with an empty determiner (like in *Women are ambitious*)

The latter two are taken from: Haegeman, L. & Guéron, Jacqueline (1999). *English Grammar. A generative perspective.*

So maybe the words you mentioned are something like nouns which can act as both discrete and non-discrete abstract nouns, or receive both an accidental (?) or a generic interpretation, but still, I'm not sure this fits your example too well and also don't know of a unique term for it.

Interesting question though, I'd be curious if there is any deeper research on precisely that difference.