# Why do most languages have a different form for singular vs plural nouns?

Tags: words, plurality

I've been wondering about this for a while. It makes sense intuitively, but I feel this is probably partly due to having been conditioned to think about it this way throughout all our lives, because it's just the way most languages work.

Coming from a mathematical background, I can see why the number 1 is different than any other number. One is the unit. Everything else is a multiple of 1.

But is there, formally, a reason why most languages treat singular nouns differently than their plural forms? Why do we add an -*s* at the end of the word in English, why does the ending change according to plurality in Italian, so on and so forth.

Like I already said, it makes sense intuitively, but I'm trying not to use intuition and habit and instead try to work out a rigorous and formal explanation for that.

Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: First, it is not true that most languages "have a different form for singular vs plural nouns". Many do. But many don't, also. Second, number is only one of the things that can get inflected on nouns - there is also case and gender, not to mention possession and definiteness. Different languages find they need to mention different things. There is no particular reason why we treat singular different from plural linguistically, but we always treat individual, countable things (which have plurals) differently from mass, liquid, or granular things (which don't have plurals, for the most part).

Comment: The majority of the languages where I live (eg Chinese languages like Mandarin, Cantonese, Hakka etc. Malay-Austronesian languages like Malay, Indonesian, Javanese, Maori etc.) don't have separate plural forms. Indian languages like Hindi, Tamil and Telugu do have plural forms but from my point of view Indian languages can be seen as Western languages

Comment: Japanese is another language that doesn't have grammatical plurals per se. There are ways to optionally specify that a noun is plural, but they aren't required by the grammar and can be omitted (and typically are if number is either implied by context or irrelevant to the discussion).

Comment: @slebetman about half of the languages of India are Indo-European languages that are strongly related to most languages of Europe, so it's obvious that they can be seen as having "western" features.

Comment: @jlawler It is true that *most* language do "have a different form for singular vs plural nouns". If look at chapters 33 and 34 on WALS, you can see that although a decent minority do indeed lack any such strategy, the majority pattern is actually to possess one. (Unless of course I myself am misunderstanding the WALS data).

Comment: As for, "we always treat [...] countable things [...] differently from mass [...] things", if you mean conceptually, you are indeed most likely correct; however, if you mean grammatically, this is quite a contentious issue (see e.g.: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/762/13303).

Comment: @jlawler "There is no particular reason why we treat singular different from plural linguistically..." How do you know there is no particular reason?

Comment: The OP is asking a "why" question, but most of the comments and answers seem to be discussing *what* languages do, not *why*. It seems like there is potentially a historical way of discussing the "why" question. I think we do know why English inflects "dog's" to express a possessive/genitive relationship -- isn't it because it was originally "dog his," and then it got contracted? I wonder if there is any known case in which a language didn't originally have inflections for number, then started marking number, so we can see how it happened.

Comment: Many languages have dual number in addition to the singular and plural.

Comment: But English is starting to lose the plural 's'(?). By native speakers, mostly.

Comment: Do any languages inflect for case but not for number?

Comment: No, user12663, it is emphatically NOT the case that "dog's" was originally "dog his". Nominal inflection - including the genitive - goes all the way back to Indo-European. A few centuries ago, somebody came up with the ingenious idea that "'s" stands for "his", and for a while there was a fad for writing "John his book", and even extending it to "Jane her book". But it was historically invalid, and the fad passed.

Answer (score 33):

First, though you probably already know this, not all languages have different forms for singular and plural nouns. Some don't mark number at all, while others have more fine-grained distinctions, using different forms for "one thing" versus "two things" versus "more than two things", or "a small number" versus "a large number". Many languages also mark nouns for things that *aren't* number, such as gender and case.

But regardless, number marking is extremely common. Quite a lot of languages do it: one of Greenberg's "universals" is that no language marks gender unless it also marks number. And it happens across all sorts of different language families with no known genetic relationship to each other.

So the most common hypothesis I've heard is that "one" versus "more than one" is a distinction that's built into the human brain at a fundamental level—in a way that, say, "eight" versus "more than eight" is not. Since this is something we recognize very early and very easily, it makes sense to indicate it in our language.

**No natural language on earth**, for example, actually has a separate form for "eight items" versus "not-eight items", or even for "two items" versus "not-two items" (that is, no language has a form meaning "either one or three-plus").

Many have a separate form for "exactly one", some have a separate form for "exactly two" (but *only* if they also have an "exactly one"), and a rare few have a separate form for "exactly three" (but *only* if there's also an "exactly one" and an "exactly two"). And these are all quantities that are quickly and instinctively recognized by infants from a very young age.

Comment: What first comes to my mind as a reason for having a distinction of one vs. many is that it's natural, or call it embedded into human consciousness: every human being differentiates between oneself and the others, me and y'all, one and many. What do you think of it?

Comment: @YellowSky The distinction between *me* and *everyone else* does not require a grammatical plural.  For example, in English, *everyone* is singular even though it includes me and you.

Comment: This reminds me of the common trope (not sure how true it is) that some primitive societies don't have distinct words for numbers beyond "one, two, many". Larger numbers don't become necessary unless there's commerce and the need to track precise amounts of things owned and traded.

Comment: Of course, the mathematician asking the question is at this point asking xyrself why you think that these languages have a marked form for _exactly_ one, when you've used those _same_ forms for _zero_ three times in this very answer.  (-:

Comment: @Henry - It was you who first mentioned "everyone else", I wrote about "the others". Naturally, "every**one**" is singular, "the others" is plural, though.

Comment: @Barmar: It was "true" in a bad sense. The tribe in question spoke larger numbers like so: "two and two and two and one" for seven. Unwieldy, but good enough for herdsmen.

Comment: RE: "(that is, no language has a form meaning "either one or three-plus")." There definitely are languages that do exactly that, but it is quite uncommon. For example Jemez has Class III nouns which may be marked for dual, and are otherwise non-dual: [dééde: 'one, or at least three shirts'], [déédesh: 'two shirts']. And similar weirdness exists in other Tanoan languages like Kiowa.

Comment: @OmarandLorraine Good point! I've read about Kiowa since posting this answer and it's a fascinating counterexample. But one could argue it's not that Kiowa has a "not-dual" number: it's that it has singular, dual, and plural, and for certain classes the singular and plural have merged.

Answer (score 6):

It is worth mentioning the fact that there seems to be some correlation between the numbers which languages may mark, and the numbers which human brains can treat differently. We can [subitise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subitizing) small numbers, 1 to approx. 5, and so far as we've observed, languages are completely unable to mark for any number outside this range.

This suggests that the motivation for grammatical number is neurological somehow.

Comment: That's possible; but other things that many languages mark on nouns (eg noun-class, case, alienabililty, respect) are not directly correlated with the perceptual world, which makes this argument look a bit like an explanation looking for something to explain.

Comment: Subitisization is a necessary condition, but it's far from sufficient, so there is little basis for thinking there is much connection.

Comment: @Accumulation why would you say it is not sufficient?

Comment: Slavic languages have different plural for quantities (2,3,4) and (5+). Possibly related. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

A single noun is fundamentally different from a plural one, because once you have more than one of something, ascribing an action or property becomes nontrivial. You have the issue of quantifiers. On one extreme you have the universal quantifier: "Friends don't let friends drink" implicitly means "All friends don't let friends drink". On the other end, there's the existential quantifier: "I have bananas at my house" implicitly means "There exists bananas at my house"; clearly it's not "all bananas are at my house. Then there are quantifiers in between, such as "most".

Comment: What makes you think that it is the absence of an overt quantifier in _Friends don't let friends drink_ that implies the universal quantifier? In English, plural noun phrases without a determiner are considered to be indefinite, and that's all to it. _I'm meeting friends_ doesn't implicitly mean "I'm meeting all friends", and _Friends are visiting later_ doesn't implicitly mean "All friends are visiting later". With regard to your _bananas_ example, the meaning of "existing" doesn't come from the noun, but from the verb: _I hate bananas at my house_ implies no existential quantification.

Comment: @Schmuddi "What makes you think that it is the absence of an overt quantifier in Friends don't let friends drink that implies the universal quantifier?" I don't. "In English, plural noun phrases without a determiner are considered to be indefinite" No, the quantifier is determined by context.